# block image/jpeg;base64 using url filter

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I using WebViewClient's `shouldInterceptRequest` function to filter photos in my android webView.

**The problem**
I'm trying to block google's base64 URL photos (like:`data:image/jpeg;base64,+`) using this regex `data:image/(jpg|png|jpeg);base64,` but without success.

I done my research and found [that](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/1260#issuecomment-173216057):

> these base64 background images are injected with JS.

but I don't know to continue.

my code:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();
    if (imgCheck(url,res))
    {

        return new WebResourceResponse(
                BrowserUnit.MIME_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN,
                BrowserUnit.URL_ENCODING,
                new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes())
        );
    }
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}
```

---

```
private static boolean isImage(String url, Resources res) {
        BufferedReader imageUrlRegex = openRawFile(res, R.raw.image_regex);
        try {
            String line = imageUrlRegex.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(line);
                if (pattern.matcher(url).find())
                    return true;
                line = imageUrlRegex.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

```
data:image/(jpg|png|jpeg|svg|ico|webp|tif|tiff|bmp|eps|apng|avif|jfif|pjpeg|pjp|cur);base64,
```

**note : I tried block like this `return url.contains("data:image");` still nothing

Comment: Can you show the code you tried, make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).